# Patterns to not lock large collections when doing maintenance work (e.g. deleting entries)?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, concurrency

One question I recurrently face is how to efficiently have writers use a collection (mostly add to it) and at the same time have maintenance logic not lock the collection or slow down writers. Is there any pattern that efficiently achieves this or is using concurrent collections the only way to go?

Comment: What kind of collection do you have in mind? `List`? `Dictionary`? Also is there a pattern on the maintenance work? For example old entries are removed?

Comment: List and you guessed well the maintenance work is exactly that of removing older entries from the list

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be to use a segmented list, a list backed-up by two internal segments (`List`'s). To read a value from the collection you should look at both segments, so there would be a read overhead. To delete old entries from the collection you would just replace the older segment with a new empty segment (the old segment would be recycled).

This idea may be viable if you don't read from the collection too often.